# What's wrong with this argument that $[0,1]$ is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Every real number in $[0,1]$ has a decimal expansion $0.d_1d_2d_3...$, so construct an infinite tree rooted at 0 where each node has branches leading to $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} $, and let each path through the tree represent the successive decimal digits of a real number. To enumerate them, go through the tree breadth-first i.e. layer-by-layer.

Comment: What's wrong? For starters, it's wrong. Secondly, it was addressed uncountably many times before on this website. Please try to search around before posting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it’s true that the tree has only countably many nodes, it has **uncountably** many branches, and the real numbers in $[0,1]$ correspond to the branches, not to the nodes. In fact the nodes correspond only to the real numbers that have terminating decimal expansions, which are a proper subset of the rational numbers.